# AS3, Flash - Save Logs of Trace in somewhere?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to save logs of Trace somewhere, so that I can look up traces for players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but for that you need a logger function instead of trace(). By the way, if you compile your SWF in release mode, no traces will happen. Say like this one:

```
private static var COMPLETE_LOG:String='';
public static function log(...args):void {
    var i:int; var s:String='\n';
    for (i=0;i<args.length;i++) {
        if (i>0) s+=' ';
        s+=args[i].toString();
    }
    COMPLETE_LOG+=s;
}
```

Use log() instead of trace() to capture traces you need. And then say upload that COMPLETE_LOG somewhere.

Comment: So I should just upload a file called COMPLETE_LOG? And I can't see where I should enter the directory for it..

Comment: It's not a file, it's a String variable that will contain all your logs. Flash does not automatically save files anywhere, only on user demand. To upload, you need a mechanism to accept such uploads first, and the solution will depend on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I found a method to post informations to a PHP file, and was thinking of just doing such, and then I will just send all 'trace's to the PHP and let it save it.. Isn't that a good idea aswell? Or would this be a bad idea?

Comment: Basically correct. You send a request with one of the parameters be this string (UUencode it or unescape to make it parsable by PHP), and process it on the server as a complete set of traces. If you need real-time trace sending, do that instead of logging into a local variable.